# Excel VBA Userform crash by various Images beeing uploaded

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a programme where the user clicks a button on the main worksheet and a Userform will be opened. That Userform basically consists of a Imageframe and another button. By Clicking the Button the Imageframe changes its background color after every 0.2 Seconds. It looks like a little color video. After about 10 seconds the 'video' should stop and a selected picture should be uploaded to the frame.

I have the great problem, that my userform crashes after a certain amount of time during the 'video' is showed. It is frustrating and i cannot understand the problem, because it randomly crashes sometimes after 5 seconds, another time after 8 seconds etc. After the crash the worksheet is showed and the userform is hidden behind.

My question is if someone knows how i prevent the userform to crash OR if after there is a command to bring the userform up to the first layer automatically.

this is my code for the button-click:

```
    For i = 1 To 15     'loop for showtime color sequenz
        Randomize
        DisplayUserform.NameBox.Caption = MainSheet.Cells(Int(nrempl * Rnd + 1), 11)
        Randomize
        DisplayUserform.DisplayImage.BackColor = RGB(Int(255 * Rnd + 1), Int(255 * Rnd + 1), Int(255 * Rnd + 1))
        DisplayUserform.Repaint
        stoptime = stoptime + 30
        Sleep stoptime
    Next

    DisplayUserform.DisplayImage.Picture = LoadPicture("C:\Users\uib25432\Pictures\Mitarbeiter\" & guilty & ".jpg")
    DisplayUserform.NameBox.Caption = guilty
```

Comment: What -precisely- does "crashes" mean? Do you get a run-time error? If so, which?

Comment: crashes in this case means that I get a 'no respond' message, and directly after that the userform shuts down. I have to click the excel-icon again on my taskbar to reactivate the userform.

Comment: I don't see how clicking the Excel icon would bring back the userform if it was closed.